# Sharing data between controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I learn how sharing data between controllers, but I encounter some problem.

I have such html view:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.message"/>    
        {{data.message}} 
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.message"/>    
        {{data.message}}    
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="thirdCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.message"/>    
        {{dataTwo.messageTwo}}
    </div>  
</div>
```

My script look like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module("MyApp",[]);

myApp.service("Data", function() {
    return {
        message : "Hello World",
    }
 });

function firstCtrl($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data; 
};

function secondCtrl($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;     
};

function thirdCtrl($scope, Data) {

    $scope.data = Data; 
    $scope.dataTwo = {
        messageTwo : $scope.data.message    
    };

};
```

I connect my controllers by using "Service". Everything work good but in third controllers "dataTwo.messageTwo" not changing when I passing new value to input field.Value of dataTwo.messageTwoi is the whole time same ("Hello World").

What I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756631/how-to-create-a-two-way-data-binding-between-two-isolated-controllers-and-a-shar/24913983#24913983

Answer (score 4):

`dataTwo.messageTwo` is not binded to `$scope.data.message`. it just get its value once during creation of the controller. so it is not possible to do binding that way.
If you want dataTwo to be changed you need to define it in the input model like this: `ng-model="dataTwo.messageTwo"`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your third ng-model

```
<div ng-controller="thirdCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="dataTwo.messageTwo"/>    
    {{dataTwo.messageTwo}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `$watch` the message for changes and update the second object accordingly like so:

```
function thirdCtrl($scope, Data) {

    $scope.data = Data; 

    $scope.dataTwo = {
        messageTwo : $scope.data.message
    };

    $scope.$watch('data.message', function (message)
    {
        $scope.dataTwo.messageTwo = message;
    });

};
```

But you should't abuse `$watch` and depending on what you are trying to achieve you might be able to refactor the code and do it another way.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `messageTwo : $scope.data.message` a new object is created on child scope and the value is assigned to `messageTwo`. This means changes to `$scope.data` will no longer be reflected in `messageTwo`. If you still want to update `messageTwo` then write a watch.

```
$scope.watch('data.message',  function (newValue, oldValue) {
  $scope.dataTwo.messageTwo = newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$watch` if you want to synchronize `data.message` with `dataTwo.messageTwo` without changing model in `ngModel`. Or you can go a little funny with ES5 [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
$scope.dataTwo = {};

Object.defineProperty($scope.dataTwo, 'messageTwo', {
    get: function() {
        return $scope.data.message;
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/2BRJNzOyfVxrAqIS0dXs?p=preview

<sub>Note: defineProperty in this example IE9+.</sub>