# ng-Click affects to different controller

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I am using angularjs UI bootstrap to make tabs. I have buttons in navbar that switches to different tabs. navbar with its own controller is nested inside the main controller. I wanted to know on how to make the buttons in the navbar switch tabs too.

i have a plunk [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/555LkZaxXQykG1tO2XbJ?p=preview)
or html and js below

```
<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
<header>

  <div ng-controller="navbarcontroller">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" >Brand
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-class="!navCollapsed && 'in'">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="pointer-events: auto;">
        <li>
            <!-- this buttons dosnt works --> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="active = 1">Select 1st tab</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="active = 2">Select 2nd tab</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<p> -----  navbar controller ends here ----- </p>

<hr>

  <p> ---- tab controller starts here ------ </p>
   <!-- this buttons  works --> 
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="active = 1">Select 1st tab</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="active = 2">Select 2nd tab</button>

  <uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab index="1"  heading="Tab1" >
      Content 1
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2"  heading="Tab1" >
      Content 2
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

this is the js file

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo')

.controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {

})


.controller('navbarcontroller', function ($scope, $window) {

});
```

Comment: It looks like your `navbarController` actually ends two lines above where you noted.

Comment: Could you provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Maybe a jsfiddle or a plunker...

Comment: @Pytth  yes thats just to indicate the end .

Comment: @lealceldeiro   https://plnkr.co/edit/555LkZaxXQykG1tO2XbJ?p=preview   i have it in the post as well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **share** your **`active` property** between both controllers. For that we need to change a little bit some things.

**1-** You have to implement a service (let's call it `tabSelector`), something like this:

```
.service('tabSelector', function(){
});
```

**2-** Now, in both `TabsDemoCtrl` and `navbarcontroller` you need to use the previously created service and implement two functions which use the `tabSelector` service, like this:

```
//this should be done with 'TabsDemoCtrl' and 'navbarcontroller' (this last one was omitted for brevity)
.controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $window, tabSelector) {

    //set the active tab
    $scope.selectTab = function(tab){
      tabSelector.active = tab;
    }
    //keep synced the active tab
    $scope.getActive = function(){
      return tabSelector.active;
    }

})
```

**3-** In your view:

- Replace the content of the `ng-clik`(`active = 1`) with this : `selectTab(1)` (functions in the controllers). Note that you have to replace `1` for the proper value.
- And the content of `<uib-tabset active="active">` for `<uib-tabset active="getActive()">`

---

*Please, refer to [**this working example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/190spe?p=preview)* (your plunker forked)

---

You can find some related info here:

1. [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)
2. [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)
3. [How to share data between controllers in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525121/how-to-share-data-between-controllers-in-angularjs)
4. [Sharing data between controllers in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953842/sharing-data-between-controllers-in-angularjs)

Comment: that works like a charm. 

Thanks a ton for the detailed explanation. it helped me integrate into my main app :)